# Which pair of lugs do the batteries connect to in an Ultra-1000AP (Powercom BNT-1000AP?) UPS

Tags: ups

A few weeks ago, I removed the (dying) batteries from my Ultra 1000AP UPS to confirm their exact type before ordering new ones. I then got distracted by something, and forgot about the project for a while.

(For what it's worth, I've found posts on a Russian forum suggesting that it's a rebadged Powercom BNT-1000AP, and post on an Italian forum that seems to suggest that the Eurogroup Spikes-UP100 Pro has the same circuit board inside).

As luck would have it, I just discovered there are actually TWO adjacent terminals labeled BAT+ (IN1 & IN2), and two adjacent terminals labeled BAT- (IN4 & IN5). As far as I can tell, there's no hint printed anywhere indicating which two the battery wires are supposed to be connected to (or whether it matters). If somebody with this UPS could open it up and take a peek to see which ones the wires are connected to, I'd greatly appreciate it.

If it matters, JP1 (220/60hz) is open, and JP3 has 3&4 shorted, with 1&2 and 5&6 open. According to the legend on the board, that correlates to "120/240".

On a purely random note, if anybody has any idea what JP2 ("NL SD") does, I'd love to know.

Likewise, if anybody knows what MCU it uses, I'd also love to know.

Here are the two pairs of contacts (note: the red and black wires you see are connected to the OUTPUT end. The battery's red and black leads were connected to one of each pair you see the arrows pointing to.

[image]

Here's a pic showing more of the board:

[image]

Stirring the pot a bit, here's a pic I finally managed to scrape up ( http://www.in4.pl/recenzje.htm?rec_id=610&rectr_str_numer=2 ) of a similar one, but I'm not ready to blindly assume it's the right pair of lugs for MY ups, because it's a slightly newer circuit board (804v1.0 instead of 801v1.1), and more importantly, it's a 220v Polish model instead of a 110v American one. I suspect that the circuit board itself hasn't changed much (in fact, the 804 board looks more or less identical to my 801 board), but I'm not prepared to rule out the possibility that 220v configurations might have the battery leads connected to a different pair of lugs. I really need to either find a pic of a US/Canadian/Mexican model, or find a circuit diagram for the BNT-1000AP (with BNT-801 circuit board) that conclusively identifies why there are 4 lugs for two battery wires.

[image]
[image]

Here's one I found in a Turkish forum ( http://forum.donanimhaber.com/m_11377295/mpage_2/key_/tm.htm ) that has the exact same board as mine (BNT-801v1.1), but I have no idea WTF is going on with the battery leads in the pic. I think he actually had both leads disconnected, and the black lead just happened to be randomly grazing the general vicinity of a "+" terminal. Either way, it's another 220v configuration, so it's still non-authoritative absent a diagram to the contrary.

[image]

Just to keep things lively, I found more pics of a BNT-1000AP on another Turkish site ( http://www.incele.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=34:incelemeler&id=130:powercom-ups&Itemid=77 ) , except this one shows the red lead connected to IN3, and the black lead connected to IN5. Wait a sec... **IN3** ?!? Oh dear...

[image]

Here's another one, in traditional Chinese, jumpered for 115/230v, using IN2 and IN5 ( http://ups--bnt-1000ap.blogspot.com/2010/11/ups-bnt-1000ap.html ):

[image]
[image]

Another Chinese site with pics ( http://duskblue616.pixnet.net/blog/post/25824076-%5B%E5%91%A8%E9%82%8A%5D%E7%A7%91%E9%A2%A8%E9%BB%91%E6%AD%A6%E5%A3%ABbnt1000ap )... negative on IN4, can't see what red is connected to.

[image]

**Score so far:**

Polish 1200UA, 115/230v, BNT-801v1.1 (2002.10.04) = IN2+, IN4-

Turkish 1000UA, 110/220v, BNT-801v1.1 (2002.??.??) =  unknown

Turkish 1000UA, 110/220v, BNT-80????? = IN3+ (WTF?!?), IN5-.

Chinese 1000UA, 115/230v, BNT-801v???? = IN2+, IN5-

Chinese 1000UA, 115/230v, BNT-801v1.1 = (unknown red), IN4-.

I really want to find a circuit diagram for the BNT-1000AP like the one posted for the 600AP. There appear to have been a bunch hosted at megaupload, but they're all gone now :(

Comment: This is off-topic for Serverfault.  Might belong on Electronics.  Messing about inside UPSes is a great way to turn from being a Sysadmin into a Deadadmin.  Seriously.  Put it down, and step away from what you don't understand, because in this case, what you don't know, can hurt you.

Comment: You keep going... Just call support.

Comment: Well, judging by the number of followers and favorites, there are at least a few others out there who think it's worthwhile and interesting. So I'm keeping it up to date with my (several hours at this point) research in case somebody else accidentally disconnects the leads in THEIR ups someday and doesn't realize until it's too late that there are two of each. Although at this point, I'm seriously starting to think that they might be connected in parallel (the + terminals directly, the - terminals after the fuse), because there seems to be no sense or logic behind which one is used in pics.

Comment: If somebody wants to migrate this to "electronics", they're welcome to do so. I do take offense at the comment that I don't "understand" it. I understand UPS workings quite well, which is *precisely* why I haven't just  tried various permutations of the 4 terminals (or tried removing the board to look at the underside), and why I'm trying to find the right answer *first*. As far as calling them goes, "Ultra" is CompUSA/TigerDirect's no-name house brand. It's a rebadged UPS. I doubt whether anyone working for Ultra even knows what a schematic *is,* let alone has a *copy* of it.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a jumper between the two batteries. The red wire should connect to the positive (BAT+) terminals on the circuit board and the battery. The black goes to the negative terminal. If this is still unclear, give [Ultra tech support](http://mail.ultraproducts.com/support_info.php) a call.

Also see the solution for CB1270 batteries [here](http://www.fixya.com/support/t6698393-correctly_install_batteries_in_ultra).

Edit:

This is not a BNT-600A. The board you've photographed clearly displays "BNT-801". The BNT-600 block diagram is displayed below. You could extrapolate the wiring arrangement from the 1-cell 600A unit to your 2-cell 801 unit.

Or just call support...

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the circuit board has TWO OF EACH with the same label. In other words, there are two terminals marked "BAT+" to which the red wire could be connected, and two terminals marked "BAT-" to which the black wire could be connected. The two "BAT+" terminals (IN1 and IN2) are adjacent, and the two "BAT-" terminals (IN5 and IN6) are adjacent.

Comment: Call support *or* post photos.

Comment: Pics are posted.

Comment: Why didn't you just call support for a definitive answer?

Comment: Because the likelihood of somebody in support having an official answer (or any answer at all) in their approved customer service dialogue script is likely to be somewhere between 'slim' and 'none'?  On further reflection, you're probably right about it not being a BNT-600A... it might be a BNT-1000AP (the specs are a closer match, but the BNT has rs232 & mine has USB). Where did you find the diagram you posted? Is there one for the 1000AP, perhaps? My UPS has two batteries, but only a single red and black lead. The batteries themselves are connected in series through a jumper lead.